# How to replace all the elements of an array in a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoose, database

If I have a new string array (`arr`) and want to replace an array in the mongoDB document accessed by a string component of the mongoDB document with this array how I do this?

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't work:

```
Posts.update({user: userVar},{ tags: arr }});
```

What I've seen online so far seems really awkward and seems to need 2 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a straight forward update.

```
 Posts.update({user: userVar}, {$set: { tags: arr }});
```

In `mongo`

```
> db.so34562815.find( ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56875d7a6a21dd6b99743439"),
    "user" : "test",
    "tags" : [
        "one",
        "two"
    ]
}

> arr = ['three']
[ "three" ]

> db.so34562815.update({user:'test'},{$set: {tags:arr}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.so34562815.find( ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56875d7a6a21dd6b99743439"),
    "user" : "test",
    "tags" : [
        "three"
    ]
}
```